# Using arrays with asp.net and VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, arrays

Sorry, I'm sure this is something that has been covered many times, but I can't find quite what I am after.

I have a single row data table which contains various settings which are used within my web system. I have been toying with turning this into an XML document instead of the single row datatable, would that make more sense?

Anyway, so, given that this is one record, there is a field called "locations," this field contains data as follows:

```
locationName1,IpAddress|locationName2,IpAddress|etc
```

The ipAddress is just the first 5 digits of the IP and allows me to ensure that logins to certain elements (admin section managed by staff) can only be accepted when connected from a company computer (ie using our ISP) - this is a largely unnecessary feature, but stops kids I employ logging in at home and stuff!

So, as the user logs in, I can check if the IP is valid by a simple SQL query.

```
SELECT ips FROM settings WHERE loginLocations LIKE '%" & Left(ipAddress, 5) & " %'
```

What I need to be able to do now, is get the name of the users location from the dataField array.

I've come up with a few long winded looping procedures, but is there a simple way to analyse

```
locationName1,IpAddress1|locationName2,IpAddress2|etc
```

as a string and simply get the locationName where LoginIp = IpAddressX

... or am I going about this in a totally ridiculous way and should turn it into an xml file? (which will then create a whole load of other questions for you about parsing XML!!)

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Answer (score 0):

u can split the string in Vb.net and the send it to a query or anything

```
'Split the string on the "," character
    Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {","c})
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to split it, but how do I query that?
If I split it with the pipes, and then loop through that splitting it by comma I can see I could make a looping setup that could find it, but that seems long winded for the purpose?

Comment: You can send 3 or 4 ips to a procedure in your db, and make something like  :   WHERE IPADDRESS IN (ip1,ip2,ip3).  Do you know how to make a conection to your Sql ?

Comment: Um, I'm fine querying the database with SQL, I'm having an issue I guess querying within a field. This data, the whole string, is held within one field in the database, called "locations", there is not a different record for each location with an ipAddress field.

Comment: mmmm, what comes to my head at this momment, is that, u can split in Sql and insert the splitted fields into a temp table, then u can query what u want in the new temp table

Comment: I see.Can't help thinking I should just make my settings data into an XML doc <locations><location1><locationName>name</locationName><locationIP>12.12</locationIP><location2> etc... </locations> Only trouble with that is I don't know much about using XML as a datasource and querys with XML

Comment: check this, maybe it could help you    http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise that you break those our into database columns and each location is a separate row; had it been done that way in the first place, you wouldn't have the problem you have now.

But since you have it in a single row/column, why not bring that back and simply get the value from .NET?

```
    Dim Source As String = "TestLocationA,127.0|TestLocationB,128.0|TestLocationC,129.0"
    Dim Test As String = Source
    Dim ToFind As String = "127.0"

    Test = Test.Substring(0, Test.IndexOf(ToFind & "|") - 1)
    Test = Test.Substring(Test.LastIndexOf("|") + 1)

    MsgBox(Test)
```

OR

```
Public Class Form1
    Private IpLocationList As New List(Of IpLocation)
    Private IpToFind As String = ""

    Private Class IpLocation
        Public Name As String
        Public IP As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal FullLocation As String)
            Me.Name = FullLocation.Substring(0, FullLocation.IndexOf(","))
            Me.IP = FullLocation.Substring(FullLocation.IndexOf(",") + 1)
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private Function FindIP(ByVal IpLocationItem As IpLocation) As Boolean
        If IpLocationItem.IP = IpToFind Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Source As String = "TestLocationA,127.0|TestLocationB,128.0|TestLocationC,129.0"
        Dim LocationList As New List(Of String)

        LocationList.AddRange(Split(Source, "|"))

        For Each LocationItem As String In LocationList
            IpLocationList.Add(New IpLocation(LocationItem))
        Next

        IpToFind = "127.0"
        Dim result As IpLocation = IpLocationList.Find(AddressOf FindIP)
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            MsgBox(result.Name)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
enter code here
```

This has the benefit of loading the array one time and not needing to manually loop through arrays.

Comment: Thanks SpectralGhost... that nearly did it. I can't split the data into rows because it has to be assigned to a single record, it won't work with the rest of the data if I do that. The best result I can come up with is as below, which I was concerned with being inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, these are the functions of interest in extracting a sub-string:

```
CHARINDEX

SUBSTRING

LENGTH
```

You can google the details about them (e.g. CHARINDEX at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx). With these, you'll need to use computed columns in your query to extract that location name.

If it's not too late, you may want to devise a new way to layout these elements. For instance, instead of:

```
locationName1,IpAddress1|locationName2,IpAddress2|etc
```

How about

```
{IpAddress1,locationName1}{IpAddress2,locationName2}etc
```

That way you can use CHARINDEX to locate "{" & Left(ipAddress, 5); from that position, locate ","; then from that position locate the closing "}". From there it should be straightforward to use SUBSTRING to get at the locationName. Be forewarned that this will likely be a messy query (probably built from a few sub-queries, one for each position).

In the end, SpectralGhost's idea to just read in the column and do the extraction in VB is probably the way with the least hassle.

Comment: Thanks @rskar that's nearly there too. The query becomes very messy though, as you said and, as I'm only dealing with one record I don't think it need be that complex.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to do it this way, but would appreciate comments on efficiency.

I've split ipAddress and locationName into two database columns, within the one row, and getting the required data by comparing strings as arrays, as per the code below.

For this particular application I'm only dealing with one record, so it's pretty simple. However, further down the line, I need to product a system for monitoring product sales. from an invoices table.

Each invoice record is a row in the database with items in the invoice held similarly, [item1],[item2] etc. There is another column for quantities [qty1],[qty2] etc, prices [price1],[price2], etc. I'll need to be able to search the database for invoices in which an item number occurs (easy SQL WHERE itemList LIKE %[invNO]%) and then compare arrays to get the quantities and individual prices of each item on that invoice. Extracting these rows as arrays and locating the relevant position in these as per the code below, will work fine, but when the whole operation is looping through several hundred or thousand rows, will this become really slow?

```
    ipList, locationList = list as comma separated string from database record field

    Dim ipArray As Array = Split(ipList, ",")
    Dim locationArray As Array = Split(locationList, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ipArray)
        If Left(ipArray(i), 5) = Left(ipAddress, 5) Then
            arrayPosition = i
            itemFound = "True"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    location = locationArray(arrayPosition)
    'loop through ips then get the position and make the location equal to that
    If itemFound <> "True" Then
        inValidIP = "True"
    End If
```

Comment: Since you've asked about efficiency: The above way involves reading in two large strings from the database, and then the creation of a bunch of little strings alongside whatever arrays of references are needed to instantiate the Arrays. This is followed by a sequential search to locate an element in one of the Arrays; which in turn requires more little string creations via the call to Left(). There is also an issue of ensuring the elements of the ipAddress and locationName arrays are properly aligned.

Comment: For a small application, none of this is a big deal, but as a server gets busier, the above approach will involve a lot of garbage collection (from all the string creation). Also note that you're effectively downloading your entire "database" of ipAddress and locationName arrays everytime you want to get at the ip's and name's; if network access is involved in getting to the database, that's a lot of excess network traffic you're incurring.

Comment: I wish to be helpful and not cruel, but this idea of cramming arrays of values into columns just for the sake of keeping all relevant data within a single row is not only a naive approach but also painfully awkward and inefficient in practice - particularly if you anticipate a situation of "several hundred or thousand rows."

Comment: Better to do that properly in a relational database. Even in this little "ipAddress and locationName" problem, it would have actually been so much easier to make another table for the purpose. Your SQL would then look something like SELECT LocationName FROM ApprovedWorkstations WHERE IpAddress LIKE "00.00.%".

Comment: Hmm... I am concerned about the efficiency. This particular application is dealt with entirely by my example and I'm not bothered in that case, but when I come to try to extract sales stats, I do want it to be more efficient. Neither application will be bothered by many users, but the amount of data is going to present a problem for the latter application. I just can't work out how to structure the tables to get sales stats, and be able to work on them. I need sales stats per product over time, and need to be able to remove sales where refunds are applied.